# created external site - but I'd like sharepoint to search it?

Tags: asp.net

I've created an external site outside of sharepoint completly.  It's just a basic site that allows our users to get to specific sites.  I wanted to simply embed this site via a url inside of sharepoint (I guess there is a web site page web part).  This works fine...but is there any way to have sharepoint search / index this site?  I do not want to create this site inside of sharepoint.  It's simply a asp.net web site that is outside of sharepoint but we need to bring the interface into sharepoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [Page Viewer web part](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/page-viewer-web-part-HA010024045.aspx) which basically presents the external site within a SharePoint page using an IFRAME.

However, getting SharePoint to Search that other site is a completely different matter and would require that you enter the external URL into a Content Source in your Search Administration.  Since this is a non-SharePoint site, you would probably have to create a new Content Source for it.  You would also have to grant at least Read permissions for the search crawl account to the external site.

Comment: SO what you are saying is that it is still possible to do this and have it search / crawl the site?

Comment: Definitely possible but it does require the separate step of configuring your Search to index the external site as well.

Comment: Dave I dont have much knowledge about sharepoint.  Is there some steps or URL you could lead me to help me out.

Comment: This is for FAST but the basic steps are the same : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dark_corners/archive/2012/03/06/poc-part-3-crawling-an-external-web-site-with-the-sharepoint-2010-web-crawler.aspx